# Define body is another define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I cannot explicitly find an answer to this, seems to work in practice:

```
// example #1
#define test 5
#define test2 test
```

`(test2 == 5) == true`

And even this:

```
// example #2
#define test2 test
#define test 5
```

Is there an explicit **C** spec rule that allows this. I thought the preprocessor is pretty simple and it just does find/replace. But I guess in the case of `#define test2 test` it knows test is not a string, so it might be a `define`? So the preprocessor does multiple scans just for this type of scenario?

My main question, why does my example #2 work?

Comment: It just does find/replace, in the order that the `#define`s are written. So, this is expected behavior.

Comment: *"it knows test is not a string"* - the preprocessor knows nothing apart from text substitution.

Comment: @EdCottrell, see my example #2. Where test2 is defined first. When I print test2, why does it come out as 5? The order of the defines would break example #2.

Comment: Think about it. If you evaluate `test2 == 5` and replace `test2` with `test`, then replace `test` with `5`, what do you get? The `#define`s are evaluated in order, but that doesn't mean that all values used therein must already be `#define`d.

Comment: @EdContrell so it seems on every define, it rescans the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessing result of:

```
#define test2 test
#define test 5

test2
test
```

gives:

```
5
5
```

even with `test` being defined after `test2`. The preprocessor rescans the source as specified in:

> (C99, 6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement p1) "After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ## processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned, along with all subsequent
>   preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace."

Answer (score 0):

How the first gets processed:

```
#define test 5
#define test2 test
something with test
something with test2

#define test2 5
something with 5
something with test2

something with 5
something with 5
```

How the second gets processed:

```
#define test2 test
#define test 5
something with test
something with test2

#define test 5
something with test
something with test

something with 5
something with 5
```